# How to define the tensor product via an initial morphism?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, tensor-products

I am just getting to know some category theory.

My understanding of the "universal property" (based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property#Formal_definition) Wikipedia article) is that it is characterized in terms of an "initial morphism" or "terminal morphism". As an example, suppose $\mathcal{B}\in \text{Set}$, $\text{Vect}$ the category of vector spaces over some field, $\mathcal{F}:\text{Vect} \to \text{Set}$ the forgetful functor, and $V_{\mathcal{B}}$ a complex vector space with basis $\mathcal{B}$. Then the fact that a vector space is free over its basis implies that given $W\in \text{Vect}$, there is a unique $\tau \in \text{Hom(Vect)}$ such that the following diagram commutes:

$$\begin{array}{c} \mathcal{B} & \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} & \mathcal{F}(V_{\mathcal{B}})& V_{\mathcal{B}}\\ & \searrow_{f} & \downarrow_{\mathcal{F}(\tau)} & \downarrow{\tau} \\ &&\mathcal{F}(W) & W \end{array}$$

Similarly, we can define the direct sum of vector spaces by the below diagram, where $\Delta: \text{Vect} \to \text{Vect}\times \text{Vect}$ is the diagonal map:

$$\begin{array}{c} U,V & \overset{g_1, g_2}{\longrightarrow} & \Delta(U\oplus V )& U \oplus V\\ & \searrow_{f_1, f_2} & \downarrow_{\Delta(\tau)} & \downarrow{\tau} \\ &&\Delta(W) & W \end{array}$$

In learning about the tensor product recently, I learned that it is defined via a universal property with respect to bilinear maps. But I am not able to nail down what the relevant functor is. In a diagram like:

$$\begin{array}{c} U\times V & \overset{\iota}{\longrightarrow} & \mathcal{F}(U\otimes V )& U \otimes V\\ & \searrow_{f} & \downarrow_{\mathcal{F}(\tau)} & \downarrow{\tau} \\ &&\mathcal{F}(W) & W \end{array}$$

$f$ and $\iota$ should be bilinear maps somehow, but what category does $U\times V$ belong to, and what is the functor $\mathcal{F}$?